# speed up iphone application that is loading a KML file for mapView overlays

Tags: iphone, android-mapview, kml

I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to load my KML file for my mapView overlays? The kml is pretty complex and how I am doing it seems to be bogging my app down pretty bad. I am using Apples KMLParser... As is th=is app works, but like I said, it is very slow to update when any changes are made:

```
// Get bike path Polyline
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"doc.kml"];
kml = [[KMLParser parseKMLAtURL:url] retain];   
[url release];
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you're serious about setting up a scalable environment, you should consider installing something like [MapServer](http://mapserver.org/) or [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/) on the server where you host your kml document now.

You can then decide whether to render your kml server-side (you'll get a bitmap image png/gif/jpg) or client-side (you'll fetch kml or json).

To set this up, you'll need the following:

- A [postgres](http://www.postgresql.org) database.
- GeoServer/MapServer

In the postgres database you place the shapes that you need to show.
GeoServer takes care of either rendering images, or putting together kml data from the database. It can even serve data as svg or pdf.

To finish this off, you could use [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/mobile.html) on the client side.

Anyway, whatever you do, I don't recommend wasting your time rolling your own solution.  The products I've mentioned above are very powerful and best of all: free.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I need my map to follow me so I am not sure rendering it down to an image will work... Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Just take a look at Google Maps.. it uses server-side rendered bitmaps, and that works quite smooth on your iPhone, right? GeoServer can provide similar map images. You don't have to worry about rendering it at different zoomlevels and all because that's gets done for you. You can even have cache rendered bitmaps both on serverside and clientside. If you zoom in and scroll a lot, it will probably increase network traffic though.